# Many-to-many database relationship magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, search

Hello I want to create a Magento store which is going to sell books.

Every book is going to have Authors and the database relationship will be "Many-to-Many"
**Example:** 1 book has many authors and 1 Author has many books.

How can I achieve a system like this with Magento? I tried to create an attribute Author but I can only select 1 author.

Comment: This Link will clear your all concept about all relationships in Magento.
Read carefully this Documentation its demonstration with images and links to tables Best of luck https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016505812-Understanding-and-evaluating-table-relationships

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a table to hold the relation.
So you have your book table which is actually the products table and the author table with id, name, ...
and you need an other one that holds the `book_id` and the `author_id` and maybe a position so you know in which order to list the authors.

I can recommend you [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9). It will create the code needed to administer and list the authors and allows you to link it many to many with the products.

See the documentation for product relations

- https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/wiki/crud
- https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/wiki/product-relation

---

<sub>Note: I am involved in the development of the extension but it's free to use for everyone</sub>

Comment: Thanx a lot i create my module so easy good job :)

Answer (score 1):

Use categories as authors. There you have already the type of relation you want to use. If it does not work, create a multiselect attribute and you will be able to select multiple authors for a book.

Comment: Even if the multiselect attribute might work, I don't recommend it because for example if you delete one author the reference to it will still remain in the database, and if you plan to search by author you have to do a `FINSET` which is not that fast.